# Webpack and Javascript variable scope, is it ok to use var = in all modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am building ReactJS frontends for my apps.  I use webpack to package all the javascript into a single file.  Here is the way I have been writing my modules

```
var _ = require("underscore");
var React = require("react");

var SomeComponent = React.createClass({

    render() {
      return "Some Html Here";

    }

};

module.exports = SomeComponent;
```

I use the var React = require('react') in all of them.  To my understanding using var inside a module scopes that variable to that module.  Since I will need react and some other libraries in almost every module I do is there a way to globally define?  Or should I even worry about this, is WebPack smart enough to know that my react var in one module is the same as my react var in another module?

My solution seems to work fine but I am curious if this is bad use of memory.

Comment: The `var React` in every module is a reference to a singleton, which is the React library, same thing with underscore or modules you write yourself. The only additional memory is a single pointer reference per file and you could add tens of thousands more of those before you'd run into memory problems. On top of that, Webpack is indeed being smart and sharing variables wherever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is fine. Webpack bundles your js files and uglifies them in the production build. This process takes care of loading the required libraries only as much as needed - most of the time only once (if you are not doing any crazy chunking stuff).

In addition to that, it is good practice to require all the dependencies you need in your module. That makes it more reusable, since you do not need to worry about putting some libs in the global namespace first.

When building for production, be sure to execute `webpack -p` though. Otherwise your bundle is gonna be large a.F. ;-)